# Tax applying module

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, tax

I am creating custom module. In the Module Some Customer Groups doesnot apply the tax calculation and some custom functions. so i need to know the file name and function for tax calculation in cart and checkout page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app\code\core\Mage\Tax\Model\Calculation.php
```

function is  **calcTaxAmount()**.

This the file and functions, you asked. and please dont make any custom code in core folder. it will affect your site when you update the magento version.

Comment: Yeah. @Crock. Thanks. I fixed my issue. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnS great !!!